# reverse_lazy used due to login_required on redirect but issue still remains: as a circular import

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I had a typo but only after I had worked on this code messing things up:

I was try to redirect to another form and use relative links , we ended up using redirect_lazy and having the url.py in the app as such:   url(r'^step1/$', views.step1, name='step1'),

We redirect from one form to another, when your app owns it own url, it doesnt pick up the relative url in redirect to a form: it can cause major issues... Anyway if anyone ever get stuck there I'll share the whole solution.

........................................................................
I am having an issue which I think is coming from the use of login_required . That said the fix was to use lazy_reverse which I did in the redirect, this took away the site wide crash with the same error message below. Now its isolated to the view its self. I think it is at render but I am not to sure what to do .... Any help would be great:

```
                    *makeProfile app:*
```

views.py

```
@login_required

def step1(request):

   title =" Step 1 of 4 "

   profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
   form = step1Form(request.POST or None, instance=profile)

   context ={
     "title":title,
     "form":form

}

   if form.is_valid():
     instance =form.save(commit=False)
     instance.user = request.user


     name = form.cleaned_data.get("name")
     surname = form.cleaned_data.get("surname")
     country = form.cleaned_data.get("country")
     state = form.cleaned_data.get("state")
     city = form.cleaned_data.get("city")
     statusType = form.cleaned_data.get("statusType")


     instance.name = name
     instance.surname = surname
     instance.country = country
     instance.state = state
     instance.city = city
     instance.statusType = statusType

     instance.save()

     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('makeProfile:step2'))

  return render (request, "makeProfile/step1.html", context)
```

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include ,url,patterns
from . import views

urlpatters = [

 url(r'^$', 'views.step1', name='step1'),
 url(r'^$', 'views.step2', name='step2'),
 url(r'^$', 'views.step3', name='step3'),
 url(r'^$', 'views.step4', name='step4'),

 ]
```

*root* : url.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin



urlpatterns =  [
   # Examples:
   url(r'^$', 'newsletter.views.home', name='home'),

   url(r'^question/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'questions.views.single',   name='question_single'),
   url(r'^question/$', 'questions.views.home', name='question_home'),

   url(r'^contact/$', 'newsletter.views.contact', name='contact'),
   url(r'^about/$', 'ruLinked.views.about', name='about'),

   url(r'^makeProfile/',   include('makeProfile.urls',namespace='makeProfile')),

   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
]

# if settings.DEBUG:
#   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,     document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
#   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,  document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8888/makeProfile/step1

Django Version: 1.8.3
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'crispy_forms',
'registration',
'newsletter',
'questions',
'makeProfile')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
    File "/home/g4/django/ruLinked/lib/python3.4/site-   packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  108.                 response = middleware_method(request)
   File "/home/g4/django/ruLinked/lib/python3.4/site- packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
     74.             if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info,   urlconf) and
    File "/home/g4/django/ruLinked/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in is_valid_path
     647.         resolve(path, urlconf)
    File "/home/g4/django/ruLinked/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
     522.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
    File "/home/g4/django/ruLinked/lib/python3.4/site- packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
      368.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
    File "/home/g4/django/ruLinked/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
     366.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
    File "/home/g4/django/ruLinked/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
    411.             raise   ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /makeProfile/step1
Exception Value: The included urlconf '<module 'makeProfile.urls' from   '/home/g4/django/ruLinked/src/makeProfile/urls.py'>' does not appear to   have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the   issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

There are a few answers to this on stack overflow but they resolved this with reverse_lazy on the redirect so not to sure whats going on in mine.

Thank you so much if you read all that.

Comment: Quite apart from your typo, your URLs can't possibly work; you can't have four views all pointing to the same URL.

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone.... Im mortified that I didnt see my types got so lost in the error message... will leave the answer up anyway .thx again and apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do like this;

```
urlpatterns = [

   url(r'^step1/$', 'views.step1', name='step1'),
   url(r'^step2/$', 'views.step2', name='step2'),
   url(r'^step3/$', 'views.step3', name='step3'),
   url(r'^step4/$', 'views.step4', name='step4'),

]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, it should be `urlpatterns`, not `urlpatters`.

```
urlpatters = [

 url(r'^$', 'views.step1', name='step1'),
 url(r'^$', 'views.step2', name='step2'),
 url(r'^$', 'views.step3', name='step3'),
 url(r'^$', 'views.step4', name='step4'),

 ]
```

You don't need to use `reverse_lazy` in the step1 view, because the call happens in the view, after the url config has been loaded. You can simplify your code further by using the redirect shortcut.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

return redirect('makeProfile:step2')
```